# issues in importing nltk, giving errors when ran on python3 prompt

Tags: nltk

I have installed nltk on python3.5 version using command:

> sudo apt-get install python3-nltk
>   when this did not work, I also tried using pip

when I tried checking the installations on python3 prompt it is giving me the error as this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Llu0.png)

how can I resolve this error?

Comment: nltk is not yet installed so you cannot import it. Please provide the error you get in Terminal when you try to install nltk.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python3-pip && sudo pip3 install -U nltk`

Answer (score 0):

You can install [NLTK](http://nltk.org) through PIP. First of all you have to install pip for python3.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

then check if pip installed successfully by running:

```
pip3 -V
```

and you have to take something like this

```
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
```

After use pip3 to install nltk by running:

```
sudo pip3 install -U nltk
```